# pthread_mutex, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE and memory-barrier

Tags: posix, mutex, recursive-mutex

In https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_12 it is said that recursive mutexes need not to synchronize memory.

In my understanding, they therefore do not need to establish a memory-barrier. Should I then use a memory-barrier explicitly? Say: use `asm volatile ("" ::: "memory");` ?

Comment: Recursive mutexes that a thread already owns don't need to synchronize, since they already did when they locked the first time. Likewise, a not fully unlocked recursive mutex doesn't need to synchronize because it's still owned. Why would you want an explicit memory barrier?

Comment: Oh yes, thanks! I just did not obey the phrase " ... and the calling thread already owns the mutex".